# Using setFlashMode - Android 2.2

Tags: android

Want to switch light on/off and not succeeding.  Probably not getting the most from th documentation.  In any event, this is what I have tried.

Amongst the imports I have

```
import android.hardware.Camera;
```

Within the body

```
Camera myCamera;
.......
myCamera = Camera.open();
.......
Camera.Parameters myCameraParameters = myCamera.getParameters();
myCameraParameters.setFlashMode(FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
```

The above line brings up an error 'FLASH_MODE_TORCH cannot be resolved to a variable'  I am assuming that I am missing an import which defines FLASH_MODE_TORCH.

Anyine point me in the right direction?

IF I am missing an import, where should I go in the documentation to find out what imports are needed for what statements, constants .....

Regards,

Oliver

Answer (score 2):

I believe it should be Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH.  I was having some difficulty getting visibility to this parameter, but you should [take a look at this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878294/camera-parameters-flash-mode-torch-replacement-for-android-2-1)  They seem to have it figured out with an example.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info. What I did (a pure guess on my part!) was myCameraParameters.setFlashMode("on") or "off" will turn off the light and myCameraParameters.setFlashMode("torch") turns it on.  BUT, I would like to know how/where FLASH_MODE_TORCH is set because it is coming up as unknown in my compiler/Eclipse.  There must be some way in the documentation of knowing what to include when you find a predefined constant (like FLASH_MODE_TORCH).  Any ideas?

Comment: I actually had the exact same issue.  I can't seem to get the value to show up in my IDE.  I think its a visibility issue, but I see in the doc that the constant value for FLASH_MODE_TORCH = "torch".  I'm not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

This code might help comeone else

```
            Camera.Parameters myCameraParameters = myCamera.getParameters();
            String stringFlashMode;
            stringFlashMode = myCameraParameters.getFlashMode();
            if (stringFlashMode.equals("torch"))
                    myCameraParameters.setFlashMode("on"); // Light is set off, flash is set to normal 'on' mode
            else
                    myCameraParameters.setFlashMode("torch"); // This turns the light on
            myCamera.setParameters(myCameraParameters);
```

Regards,

Oliver