# Widget for switch on camera flashlight

Tags: android, android-widget, android-camera, flashlight

I've see that there's a lot of torch app that offer also a widget for switch on flashlight. I'm trying to do my own widget for perform the same task, but i have some questions. 
I've already an app for switch on and off camera flashlight, but it use a hidden surfaceView inside layout for do that (flashlight doesn't switch on without surfaceView).
Now, as i could read from developer site, SurfaceView is not admitted inside widget layout.
What's the correct way to implement this kind of widget?

Comment: refer this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7515309/widget-for-turning-on-off-camera-flashlight-in-android
hope it will help you

Comment: refer this link as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068803/how-to-turn-on-camera-flash-light-programmatically-in-android

Comment: it's an old code, and it doesn't work on my device (nexus 5)